# How can I height: 100% my item?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed a Wordpress theme and I want an item to be 100% height for the remaining available space.

This is code HTML:

```
<header id="masthead" class="navbar navbar-default" role="banner" style="
    background: transparent;
">



<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="entry-content2">

<div class="gigi">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12  col-md-12  col-lg-12  style=" "="">
       <img src="wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/LOGOb.png" class="img-responsive center-block" style="min-width:156px;min-height:83px">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
 <!-- PLACE THIS CODE AFTER THE HEADER -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
<p class="text-center" style="color:white;font-size:17px;padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;">Am reprezentat şi am acordat consultanţă juridică pentru clienţi persoane fizice române şi străine, instituţii publice, persoane juridice române şi străine în următoarele domenii:</p>
<div class="row sss">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2" style="font-size:17px;color:white;">
<p class="text-left">Drept civil<br>
– agricultură, exploatări agricole, prelucrarea şi comercializarea produselor agricole;<br>
– comerţ cu produse alimentare;<br>
– imobiliar;<br>
– distribuţie de carburanţi;<br>
– transporturi;<br>
– asigurări;<br>
– producţie şi comercializare utilaje grele;<br>
– producţie structuri metalice;<br>
– design, fotografie, artă;
</p>
<p></p></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-0" style="font-size:17px;color:white;">
<p class="text-left">Drept administrativ<br>
– producţie automatizări;<br>
– servicii de proiectare;<br>
– comercializare automatizări;<br>
– jocuri de noroc;<br>
– turism, hoteluri şi pensiuni;<br>
– medical;<br>
– construcţii civile şi industriale;<br>
– comercializare utilaje şi autovehicule, service auto;<br>
– producţie software, administrarea site-urilor; </p>
<p></p></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-0" style="font-size:17px;color:white;">
<p class="text-left">
– comerţ;<br>
– bursier, societăţi listate, investitori, fonduri de investiţii;<br>
– asistenţă şi îngrijire copii şi vârstnici;<br>
– exploatări forestiere şi prelucrarea lemnului;<br>
– extracţia şi prelucrarea minereurilor;<br>
– producţia şi comercializarea materialelor de construcţii;<br>
– instituţii publice;<br>
– instituţii religioase.</p>
<p></p></div>
<p></p></div>
</div>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</div>







<div class="container-fluid">


 <!-- PLACE THIS CODE AFTER THE HEADER -->
    <div class="container" style="
    background: #D9D9D9;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-top: 0px;
">
        <nav class="" role="navigation">
<!--            <div class="container-fluid">-->
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>




            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">

                <!--            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">-->
                <!--                <div class="form-group">-->
                <!--                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">-->
                <!--                </div>-->
                <!--                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>-->
                <!--            </form>-->

                <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content">Skip to content</a>
                <div class="menu-menu-container"><ul id="menu-menu" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-6" class="asd menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/" class="<p>menu-image-title-before</p> menu-image-hovered">Home<span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="46" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/HOME.png" class="menu-image <p>menu-image-title-before</p>" alt="HOME"><img width="46" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/HOME2.png" class="hovered-image <p>menu-image-title-before</p>" alt="HOME2" style="margin-left: -46px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=17" class="<p>menu-image-title-before</p> menu-image-hovered">Echipa<span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="67" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/AVOCATI.png" class="menu-image <p>menu-image-title-before</p>" alt="AVOCATI"><img width="67" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/AVOCATI2.png" class="hovered-image <p>menu-image-title-before</p>" alt="AVOCATI2" style="margin-left: -67px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-21 current_page_item menu-item-29"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=21" class="<p>menu-image-title-before</p> menu-image-hovered">Clienti<span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="60" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CLIENTI.png" class="menu-image <p>menu-image-title-before</p>" alt="CLIENTI"><img width="60" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CLIENTI2.png" class="hovered-image <p>menu-image-title-before</p>" alt="CLIENTI2" style="margin-left: -60px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=23" class="<p>menu-image-title-before</p> menu-image-hovered">Onorarii<span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="78" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ONORARII.png" class="menu-image <p>menu-image-title-before</p>" alt="ONORARII"><img width="78" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ONORARII2.png" class="hovered-image <p>menu-image-title-before</p>" alt="ONORARII2" style="margin-left: -78px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=19" class="<p>menu-image-title-before</p> menu-image-hovered">Domenii de expertiza<span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="186" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/DOMENII-DE-EXPERTIZA.png" class="menu-image <p>menu-image-title-before</p>" alt="DOMENII-DE-EXPERTIZA"><img width="186" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/DOMENII-DE-EXPERTIZA2.png" class="hovered-image <p>menu-image-title-before</p>" alt="DOMENII-DE-EXPERTIZA2" style="margin-left: -186px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=25" class="<p>menu-image-title-before</p> menu-image-hovered">Contact<span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="75" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CONTACT.png" class="menu-image <p>menu-image-title-before</p>" alt="CONTACT"><img width="75" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/CONTACT2.png" class="hovered-image <p>menu-image-title-before</p>" alt="CONTACT2" style="margin-left: -75px;"></span></a></li>
</ul></div>            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
<!--            </div>-->
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</div></header>
```

Currently there is a distance between my element and the top of the device.

This is my code CSS:

```
     .entry-content2
    {
      background:url("http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/BODY-DROP.png");
    width:100%;
height:100%; //We have tried to make a change so resole this problem

    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps giving `.entry-content2 { height: 100%; }` could be only giving it a height of 100% to its container (which is `.container-fluid`). Meaning, whatever the height the container-fluid is, that's the most entry-content2 can be.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using viewport height value instead of percentage

ie: height: 90vh;

Hope this points you in the right

Comment: if you put what you said ... cut logo

Comment: well don't just put what I said, experiment with viewport values! How rude of you to give me a down vote too, shame on you, I'm introducing a new concept to you and look how you show gratitude...